# ClickOnce Target settings

Tags: c#, visual-studio, clickonce

I am trying to make a `.bat` file to publish my application using ClickOnce via command line. I found [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45572148/applicationfiles-folder-missing-when-clickonce-publish-with-command-line) here on StackOverflow, which suggests creating a new `<Target>` in the `.csproj` file. The code from the post looks like this (I removed the `clean` part):

```
<PropertyGroup>
<ProjLocation>D:\Test\Projects\ClickOncePublish\ClickOncePublish</ProjLocation>
<ProjLocationReleaseDir>$(ProjLocation)\bin\Debug</ProjLocationReleaseDir>
<ProjPublishLocation>$(ProjLocationReleaseDir)\app.publish</ProjPublishLocation>
<DeploymentFolder>D:\Test\Publish\</DeploymentFolder>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="Test" DependsOnTargets="Clean">

  <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjLocation)\$(ProjectName).csproj" 
    Properties="$(DefaultBuildProperties)" 
    Targets="Publish"/>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SetupFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\*.*"/>
    <UpdateFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\Application Files\**\*.*"/>
  </ItemGroup>


    <Copy SourceFiles="@(SetupFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DeploymentFolder)\" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(UpdateFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(DeploymentFolder)\Application Files\%(RecursiveDir)"/>
</Target>
```

The issue I have here, is that I would like the file to work for others as well. And using a hardcoded `<ProjLocation>` makes this kind of tricky. Is there any way to make the path relative, or in other ways make it work on other PCs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can found all available msbuild constants here [Common Macros for Build Commands and Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx)

They are all in your deployment environment. Your **ProjLocation** constant looks like **$(ProjectDir)**.

Anyway, if you need for step out your current directory, you can use a relative path like this:

```
$(ProjectDir)\..\..\Level2UpperSubFolder
```