# ClickOnce PublishUrl not working using MSBuild Task

Tags: msbuild, clickonce

I have a CruiseControl .NET build server running on Windows Server 2003, and I am trying to build and publish my Wpf (3.5) ClickOnce application using msbuild 4. The task in my build script  is as follows:

```
<MSBuild Projects="src\TestProject\TestProject.csproj"
                    Targets="publish"          
                    Properties="PublishUrl=c:\testwpf\;InstallUrl=http://devserver/TestProjectUpdates/;" />
```

However after running the  build the installation does not get deployed to c:\testwpf\ folder. However I can see the installation created in bin\release folder of the source.

Any idea why its not deploying the files to the specified PublishUrl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well the Property that I should be using is **PublishDir** instead of PublishUrl.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/4748f516-491b-4019-a2bb-fc3b1e99e98b

Comment: Yes, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919625/msbuild-doesnt-respect-publishurl-property-for-my-clickonce-app/2174063#2174063