# Using Team City parameters to override MS Web Deploy publish profile settings

Tags: teamcity, webdeploy

I am using Team City and Web Deploy to build and deploy an ASP.NET Web Application.

I have DEV.pubxml and QA.pubxml publish profiles configured.

I want to override the `publishUrl` property in those files through Team City so that each of my Team City build configurations can deploy to different locations on my web servers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this isn't the right property to override, and that you want PublishDir instead. See this [response to another SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2174063/2040362).