# How to publish a WPF clickonce app when building a solution?

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2015, msbuild, clickonce

I have a solution with many projects, some of which have an Outputtype of exe.

I'm using the following arguments as part of my MsBuild call

```
/target:publish /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\
```

However, this publishes all projects with an Outputtype of exe. However, I only want to publish one specific project.

Most of what I have read states to reference the named `PublishProfile`. However, I don't see a way of creating a `PublishProfile` for this project type. When I click Publish I get a basic publish wizard and the publish settings are stored in the `.csproj` file not a `.pubxml` file. So how can I request a specific project to be published?

Comment: Do you want to build the solution but only publish a specific project with one MSBuild command line? How about publish the specific project with a command line: `msbuild "xx.csproj" /target:publish /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"`?

Answer (score 0):

> However, I don't see a way of creating a PublishProfile for this project type. When I click Publish I get a basic publish wizard and the publish settings are stored in the .csproj file not a .pubxml file. So how can I request a specific project to be published?

The `PublishProfile` is used for web project not click once. Just as you said, "*basic publish wizard and the publish settings are stored in the .csproj file not a .pubxml file*", so `PublishProfile` should not be a correct option.

If you want to publish a specific project from solution with msbuild, the simple way is to build the entire solution but only publish one project file, like:

```
msbuild.exe "ProjectName.csproj" /target:publish /p:PublishDir="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\
```

If using one command line to build and publish is your persistence, you can custom a target to publish the project in the project file, which you want to publish. [For example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919625/msbuild-doesnt-respect-publishurl-property-for-my-clickonce-app):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- the folder of the project to build -->
    <ProjLocation>..\YourProjectFolder</ProjLocation>
    <ProjLocationReleaseDir>$(ProjLocation)\bin\Release</ProjLocationReleaseDir>
    <ProjPublishLocation>$(ProjLocationReleaseDir)\app.publish</ProjPublishLocation>
    <!-- This is the web-folder, which provides the artefacts for click-once. After this
     build the project is actually deployed on the server -->
    <DeploymentFolder>D:\server\releases\</DeploymentFolder>
</PropertyGroup>


<Target Name="Publish" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
    <Message Text="Publish-Build started for build no $(ApplicationRevision)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjLocation)/YourProject.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Release" Targets="Publish"/>   


    <ItemGroup>
        <SchoolPlannerSetupFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\*.*"/>
        <SchoolPlannerUpdateFiles Include="$(ProjPublishLocation)\Application Files\**\*.*"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(SchoolPlannerSetupFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(DeploymentFolder)\"
    />
    <Copy
        SourceFiles="@(SchoolPlannerUpdateFiles)"
        DestinationFolder="$(DeploymentFolder)\Application Files\%(RecursiveDir)"
    />      
    <CallTarget Targets="RestoreLog"/>
</Target>
<Target Name="Clean">   
    <Message Text="Clean project:" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjLocation)/YourProject.csproj" Properties="Configuration=Release" Targets="Clean"/>
</Target>
```

With this custom target, you do not need to publish the project, just need build the solution.

Hope this helps.